# How to add an int value (+1) in query php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to +1 a value because when I return the book, this query will run and return the book but it doesn't return the value just keep subtracting the value of book thanks for helping me

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$book_id = $_GET['book_id'];

if(isset($id)){
   $b=mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM book WHERE book_id='$book_id'");

   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($b);

   $copies=$row['book_copies'];

   $new = $copies++;

   mysqli_query($dbcon,"UPDATE book ON book_copies = $new");    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do

```
UPDATE book SET book_copies = book_copies + 1
WHERE book_id='$book_id'
```

> Although this leaves your script at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

You should be preparing and parameterising the query like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE book SET book_copies = book_copies + 1
        WHERE book_id=?";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);    // assuming integer here
$res = $stmt->execute();

if (! $res ) {
    echo $dbcon->error;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks I will implement that to my codes , is it ok to put that code just like that? even i don't have framework or anything else?

Comment: How to implement that to me because this is my all my codes https://imgur.com/a/226ya

Answer (score 0):

You are using the update statement wrong it would something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

In your case you should try something like:

```
"UPDATE book SET book_copies=$new WHERE book_id='$book_id'"
```

Comment: you should mark a response as the best, so others can know how you solved the issue.

Comment: ohhh ok because I want to combine the all comments and implement it to my codes, btw thank you for helping me thumbs up for you!